# Rails find method with conditions parameter trick

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to use one command to retrieve all rows and filter them?

So, now I have conditional logic

```
if rating_filter.nil?
  @movies = Movie.all
else
  @movies = Movie.find(:all, :conditions => {:rating => rating_filter})
end
```

i.e if filter for field is not set, I don't want to filter by this field, but if I pass nil to second command, I will get:

```
 SELECT * FROM movies WHERE rating is NULL, though I need
 SELECT * FROM movies
```

The problem arises, if I have more than one parameter. If both are set, so no problem:

```
@movies = Movie.find(:all, :conditions => {:rating => rating_filter, :date => date_filter})
```

but if one filter is not set, i need to branch my logic to get separate commands:

```
if ..
  @movies = Movie.find(:all, :conditions => {:rating => rating_filter)
else
 @movies = Movie.find(:all, :conditions => {:date => date_filter})
else
 @movies = Movie.all
end
```

Is there a trick to reduce lines of code, ideally to one? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this way with the reject function of hash

```
    @movies = Movie.find(:all, :conditions => {:rating => rating_filter, :date => date_filter}.reject{|k, v| !v})
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use the [has_scope](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope) gem.

It helps to keep your controllers clear and succinct.